# .htaccess redirect to index.php

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

My website : theexample.com
I modified my .htaccess so that if visitors visits an unkown url it redirects directly to index.php with :

```
FallbackResource index.php
```

The problem is that it works only if there is one element after "theexample.com".

for example :

- "theexample.com/shudhusdfuisdfhisdfh": works and redirects to
- "theexample.com/sh/fuisd/fhisdfh": doesn't work and doesn't
  redirect to index.php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use **absolute path** of fallback resource not a relative one:

```
FallbackResource /index.php
```

Otherwise `FallbackResource index.php` will try to load `index.php` in the provided sub-path e.g. `theexample.com/sh/fuisd/fhisdfh` will try to load `theexample.com/sh/fuisd/index.php` which will cause failure as that path doesn't exist resulting in **Internal Server Error**.

Answer (score 0):

This is rewrite. Redirect only non-files links =)

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php
```

Example: url http://example.com/asdjivuhr/34tv3t will redirext to index.php
BUT if you have files(css,js) http://example.com/script.js will stay untooched if file exists!