# Redirect to index.php breaks CSS/JS/image links

Tags: php, wordpress

I am building my own basic version of WordPress to get a better understanding of how it works.

- I have redirected all URL requests through `.htaccess` by copying the default WordPress configuration.
- I then manage the requested URL in my `index.php` file.

This all works fine, the problem is that now all of my linked CSS, images, and JS don't load. I am assuming because the requested URL now gets redirected to `index.php`. I have tried using both relative and direct links unsuccessfully.

How does WordPress manage this, or how can I retrieve the CSS, images, and JS while still redirecting all URLs to `index.php` to be managed from there?

This is a question regarding the creation of software similar to WordPress. Not regarding modifying or moving existing WordPress software.

Comment: It is not that easy to make a copy of a WP site - the direct URLs are stored throughout the database and in the config files also. You could try to fix it but my suggestion is to start again with a plugin designed for this and you can do it in minutes - see this answer here: [WordPress front end pages are not working after moving to the hosting server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62321555/wordpress-front-end-pages-are-not-working-after-moving-to-the-hosting-server/62323847#62323847)

Comment: Thanks I appreciate the advice, but the point is to get basic functionality purely for understanding. It is important that I don't use any frameworks.

Comment: That's not a framework - it's just a cloning tool and it (and ones like it) are widely used in the industry to overcome the problem that WP just isn't set up to easily make a copy - WP uses the full url in the db and config files, and some poorly developed themes & plugins might even save it in the files too. If you want to learn how WP works then you can try, but this is low-level stuff that requires a knowledge of WP so you'd be better off getting to grips with the basics first before delving into this (unless I misunderstood and you are not learning how it works from scratch?)

Comment: However there are other answers here to show some of the many steps you might need to take if you search the site, I'll see if I can find any for you also.

Comment: I think maybe you misunderstood. I am not looking to copy an existing WP site to another location. I am looking to build a clone of WP from scratch using php. In other words to create my own basic version of WordPress.

Comment: OK, that's not what a WP clone means! Cloning a WP site means making a working copy of an existing site, for example to move from the development environment onto to the hosting for the live site for example. A common question here is when things go wrong with the cloning, so it might be best to edit your title as this question isn't going to be helpful to users searching for help with that :)

Answer (score 1):

I found this solution which modifies the .htaccess redirect and it solved my problem:

[.htaccess redirect to index.php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32617169/htaccess-redirect-to-index-php)

Place this code in the .htaccess and all except direct links will be redirected.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php
```